# How to test for a player in a certain radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am wondering how to test for a player in a certain radius.

I've tried `/testfor @a[r=22]`, that's all I know.

Can any one help me solve my problem? I'm on Version 1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple arguments by separating them with commas. Enter the following command into a command block:

/testfor @a[name=,r=], where  is a player's username and  is the circular distance around the block.

You could put this command block on an infinite redstone loop to make it run over and over, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

And to just detect any player in the radius leave out the name and just have the radius. Example : /testfor @a[r=]